# Diode in RC Filter

Tags: diodes, filter, remote-control

Is a diode ever used in an RC filter in the configuration below to stop charge from the capacitor flowing back to the source when it falls below the cap voltage (kind of like a peak detector)? Or why isn't this done?

[image]

Comment: It's tolerable here, but in general: Label your components (R1, C1, D1, R2, C2), so that we can refer to them by name, instead of saying awkward long things like "the resistor in the lower circuit".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that, but it stops being a RC low-pass filter when you do:

When you say "R1 and C1 form an RC low-pass filter", that means you assume the output signal is the **voltage** over C1, which means that whatever "sees" that voltage has a high input impedance and doesn't actually draw significant current from the RC circuit.

That means in your lower circuit, there's no way for charge on the capacitor to ever be conducted in opposite direction to what the diode allows.

Therefore, instead of a low-pass filter, which would pass lower frequencies, and especially constant input voltage, you'd be charging the capacitor only. Not a filter! Once that capacitor has reached any voltage, you can never see a voltage below that, no matter what the input is.

---

If you really want a peak detector, yep, what you describe is how you'd do it (you'd choose a smaller capacitor though in practice, and a resistor value low enough for a short pulse to still charge your capacitor).

In a peak detector, you'd also need some way to "reset" your capacitor, so something like a transistor with the collector-emitter in parallel to the capacitor, which you can turn on to discharge the capacitor. through external control (e.g. a microcontroller).

At that point, it might make sense to simply low-pass your input signal (no diode) and sample it with a microcontroller sufficiently fast and do the detection digitally.

---

Comment: That makes sense. Say that one was wanting to filter ripple out of a power supply rail (ie. you don't really want the voltage over the capacitor to drop if the input drops), would then such a circuit involving a diode be appropriate?

Comment: @zsky3333 is your supply DC or AC? (because that question only makes sense for DC, but you put AC sources)

Comment: I guess DC with some ripple on top

Comment: Now thinking about it more, my broader question is probably, why use an RC filter on a power supply output rather than a peak detector to get rid of ripple? Wouldn't one get a less ripply output for the same size capacitor? I might ask as a separate question...

Comment: you wouldn't use an RC filter on a power supply. You'd be wasting power in the R.-

Comment: and the diode makes the removal of ripple impossible for half its cycle - so, it's really counterproductive.

Comment: Ok the pieces are falling into place. That makes sense, thank you.